# C# Calling method every minute at 55 second mark

Tags: c#, .net

I've been given a task to write a program to count how many page views are requested from our site. My current approach is to get data from google analytics Real Time API, which works to my suprise.

My problem is that to get pageviews every minute I need to poll data from google API twice (cause it returns sum of last 29 minutes + a value from a timer that resets every minute). After I set up 'the point of reset', lets just say, on a 55th second every minute, I poll data on 56th and later on at 53th second, which gives me relatively good estimation of new users / page views requested.

So this is my current approach:

```
static System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
myTimer.AutoReset = false;
myTimer.Interval = interval();
myTimer.Elapsed += myTimer_Elapsed2;
myTimer.Start();

static double interval()
   {
       return 1000 - DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
   }

static void myTimer_Elapsed2(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
   {
   if (DateTime.Now.Second == (resetPoint.Second - 1) % 60 && warden)
           {
      DoStuff();   //mostly inserting google API data to database
            }
 else if (DateTime.Now.Second == (resetPoint.Second + 1) % 60)   //so we dont get riddiculous 60 and above
   {
    //I get some data here, to later use it in DoStuff - mostly to calculate the gap between later
   }
       myTimer.Interval = interval();    //Because DoStuff() takes about 0.5 sec to execute, i need to recalibrate
       myTimer.Start();
   }
```

And it works really well, until it stops after about 2 hours, for now I have no idea why (program runs, just timer doesn't do its work anymore).

How do I make it stable for long periods of time? Best case scenario would be to run it for months without intervention.

@ I edited to give a better sense what I'm actually doing

@END CREDITS

I ended up using two timers, each running in a one minute circle. And a database writing sometimes crashed and I didn't handle the corresponding exception properly. Log told me that google API functions from time to time tend to retrieve data a bit longer, which led to multiple Threading.Event calls and made my database data handling throw an exception hence stopping the timer.

I tried to use Quartz approach but its lack of human-friendly howto made me abandon this library.

Comment: Is it possible you might have reached the Google API throttling limit?

Comment: No, google allows me to poll data 50 000 times a day, for this task I need only about 4 thousand (1440 minutes in a day * 2 + calibration at the start)

Comment: I think you can leave `% 60` out because `Second` run from 0 to 59.  And it is not needed to start the timer each time. Furthermore, when Millisecond is 999, your message queue fills up with a lot of timer messages. If it is happening at the 55'th second, you are probably overwhelming the GoogleAPI.

Comment: I'd rather wait 60sec and process data everytime then adjust the interval if needed. This way you'll be sure to avoid lost events if the system is busy and raises the event at 56 or duplicates if multiple previous events are treated at 55.

Comment: Maybe add `Debug.WriteLine("Calling Google API...");` just before `DoStuff();`. And `Debug.WriteLine("Interval: " + myTimer.Interval);` just before `myTimer.Start();`. And when entering the timer event handler,  `Debug.WriteLine("myTimer_Elapsed");`. This might give you insight in when, and how often your timer handler is called.

Comment: I do have this, and it greatly helped me in calibration. But still, my problem isn't in the task not being done, it's more like about .net timer failing to work after longer periods of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET timer is reliable. That is, it won't just stop working randomly for no apparent reason.

Most likely, something in your timer event handler is throwing an exception, which is not surfaced because `System.Timers.Timer` squashes exceptions. As [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) states:

> The Timer component catches and suppresses all exceptions thrown by event handlers for the Elapsed event. This behavior is subject to change in future releases of the .NET Framework.

That bit about the behavior being "subject to change" has been there since at least .NET 2.0.

What I think is happening is that the timer calls your event handler. The event handler or one of the methods it calls throws an exception, and the timer just drops it on the floor because you don't handle it.

You need to put an exception handler in your `myTimer_Elapsed2` method so that you can at least log any exceptions that crop up. With the information provided from the exception log, you can probably identify what the problem is.

Better yet, stop using `System.Timers.Timer`. Use [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Finally, there's no way that your code as written will reliably give you a timer tick at exactly 55 seconds past the minute, every minute. The timer isn't exact. It will be off by a few milliseconds each minute. Over time, it's going to start ticking at 54 seconds (or maybe 56), and then 53 (or 57), etc. If you really need this to tick reliably at 55 seconds past the minute, then you'll need to reset the timer after every minute, taking into account the current time.

I suspect that your need to check every minute at exactly the 55 second mark is overkill. Just set your timer to tick every minute, and then determine the exact elapsed time since the last tick. So one "minute" might be 61 or 62 seconds, and another might be 58 or 59 seconds. If you store the number of requests and the elapsed time, subsequent processing can smooth the bumps and give you a reliable requests-per-minute number. Trying to gather the data on *exact* one-minute boundaries is going to be exceedingly difficult, if even possible with a non-real-time operating system like Windows.

Answer (score 3):

You should really look into using Quartz.net for scheduling events on a reliable basis. Using a timer for scheduling is asking for stuff like race conditions, event skips and database deadlocks.

http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/ allows you to schedule events at precise intervals, independant of when your code starts or stops.

An example on how you use it: This will build a trigger that will fire at the top of the next hour, then repeat every 2 hours, forever:

```
trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("trigger8") // because group is not specified, "trigger8" will be in the default group
    .StartAt(DateBuilder.EvenHourDate(null)) // get the next even-hour (minutes and seconds zero ("00:00"))
    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
        .WithIntervalInHours(2)
        .RepeatForever())
    // note that in this example, 'forJob(..)' is not called 
    //  - which is valid if the trigger is passed to the scheduler along with the job  
    .Build();

scheduler.scheduleJob(trigger, job);
```

http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/simpletriggers.html has a few examples. I really URGE you to use it, since it will severely simplify development.

Comment: It's kinda an overkill for me, learning new library to do a rather simple task :(